# FirePHP does not show some logs in console

Tags: php, firefox, nginx, firebug, firephp

I want to output a simple string in Firebug *Console* with FirePHP.

I have  a simple test in **index.php**:

```
require_once('../system/lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);

$var = array('i'=>10, 'j'=>20);
$firephp->log($var, 'Iterators');
```

then I get log in console:
[image: Iterators: array('i'=>'10', 'j'=>'20')]

But when I add some additional firephp log in another file **b_product_settings.php**

```
class prdsetActions extends ActionsController {
        function save_product(){
global $firephp;
$firephp->log('save_product_started11');
...
        }
...
}
```

and call *save_product()* from **index.php**, then I see only first log string in *Console* tab

[image: Iterators: array('i'=>'10', 'j'=>'20')]

and two strings like **X-Wf-1-1-1-** in *Net* tab

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 19 Feb 2015 13:16:25 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 19 Feb 2015 13:16:25GMT
Location    /published/SC/html/scripts/index.php?ukey=product_settings&productID=1&search=yes&did=109&msg=9uzr
P3P CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Pragma  no-cache
Server  nginx/1.2.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Wf-1-1-1-1    165|[{"Type":"LOG","Label":"Iterators","File":"\/var\/www\/site.com\/published\/SC\/html\/scripts\/index.php","Line":"19"},{"i":"10","j":"20"}]|
X-Wf-1-1-1-2    191|[{"Type":"LOG","File":"\/var\/www\/site.com\/published\/SC\/html\/scripts\/modules\/products\/_methods\/b_product_settings.php","Line":"9"},"save_product_started11"]|
X-Wf-1-Index    2
X-Wf-1-Plugin-1 http://meta.firephp.org/Wildfire/Plugin/FirePHP/Library-FirePHPCore/0.3
X-Wf-1-Structure-1  http://meta.firephp.org/Wildfire/Structure/FirePHP/FirebugConsole/0.1
X-Wf-Protocol-1 http://meta.wildfirehq.org/Protocol/JsonStream/0.2
```

Why the second firephp log is not in *Console* tab? Any suggestions, please. I'm at an impasse.

- FirePHP 0.7.4
- Firebug 2.0.8
- Firefox 35.0.1
- PHP 5.5.21
- php.ini: output_buffering 4096
- ZendOpcache 7.0.4

Comment: This looks like a bug. I have filed an issue here: https://github.com/firephp/firephp/issues/14

Comment: Try more logging statements to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I still have this issue. Once I used var_dump() to debug a value and got "save_product_started11" string in Console tab. But I can not reproduce more. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cadorn Yes, when I put `var_dump('hello') && exit;` after `$firephp->log('save_product_started11');` I get `save_product_started11` in _Console_ tab. How var_dump() doing firephp to work?

Comment: I use nginx and php-fpm + ZendOpcache 7.0.4. May it be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug disappeared with updating Firefox to 37.0